# Detect collision into multi div superimpose

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want for my project, detect collision into multiple `div`.

Please see picture below:

1. Red box and black border is a `div`
2. Red box is movable

How detect if the red box touch one border around it?

I tried solution with canvas but is not a good way for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not the exact solution, it seems to be working for cases in which the movable div is in the intersection area of given divs.

The movable div is indicated with the id `#draggable`. All the other divs used for intersection are selected with `data-category="container"` attribute.

**HTML**

```
<div data-category="container" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:3px solid #000; position:absolute;top:10;left:10"></div>
<div data-category="container" style="width:500px;height:300px;border:3px solid #000; position:absolute;top:100;left:100"></div>
<div data-category="container" style="width:400px;height:400px;border:3px solid #000; position:absolute;top:130;left:50"></div>
<div id="draggable" style="height:20px;width:30px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:160;left:130"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
  var minTop = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var posTop, posLeft = 0;
  var minBottom = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var minLeft = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var minRight = Number.MAX_VALUE;

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      //loop through intersection divs
      $('div[data-category=container]').each(function(){
        var diffTop = $('#draggable').offset().top - $(this).offset().top; //get distance between tops
        var diffLeft = $('#draggable').offset().left - $(this).offset().left; //get distance between lefts
        var diffBottom = ($(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) - ($('#draggable').offset().top + $('#draggable').height()); //get distance between bottoms
        var diffRight =  ($(this).offset().left + $(this).width()) - ($('#draggable').offset().left + $('#draggable').width()); //get distance between rights

        //store min top
        if (diffTop > 0 && diffTop < minTop)
        {
            minTop = diffTop;
            posTop = $(this).offset().top;
        }

        //store min left
        if (diffLeft > 0 && diffLeft < minLeft)
        {
            minLeft = diffLeft;
            posLeft = $(this).offset().left;
        }   

        //store min bottom
        if (diffBottom > 0 && diffBottom < minBottom)
        {
            minBottom = diffBottom;
        }   

        //store min right
        if (diffRight > 0 && diffRight < minRight)
        {
            minRight = diffRight;
        }           
      });

      //create div within the intersection area
      $("<div id = '#divFrame' style='border:3px solid blue;position:absolute;top:" + (posTop) + ";left:" + (posLeft) + ";width:" + (minLeft + minRight + $('#draggable').width()) + "px;height:" + (minTop + minBottom + $('#draggable').height()) + "px;'></div>").appendTo("body");
  });
```

Below is how it looks like when the script is executed for the given html.

[image]

If you are using `JQueryUI`, maybe you can set the draggable object's boundries using [containment](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option as follows.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable( { containment: "#divFrame" } );
```

Comment: Waow, your solution is very fine. Thanks. Now how i can make same for circle div? please see my update

Comment: Ozgur basically did all the work for you, and now you're asking him to do even more... I'd suggest trying to _understand_ what's going on first. Two circles overlap if the distance between their centroids is smaller than their added radii.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a solution based on `Element.getBoundingClientRect` ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)). This method returns an object with 6 properties: `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`, `width` and `height`. You can use this method to find the areas your `<div>`s are covering.

Secondly, you'll have to create a method that checks if two areas overlap:

```
var rectanglesOverlap = function(rec1, rec2) {
  // Return true if overlap, false if none  
}
```

Once you have your red rectangle stored and all black bordered divs in an array you can check which of your rectangles overlap like so:

```
var overlappingRects = blackRects.filter(rectanglesOverlap.bind(null, redRect);
```

The length of the `overlappingRects` array now tells you how many overlap there is.

Let me know if you need help selecting the right elements or writing the overlap method. But there's a lot to find online about these topics already...